# How to get an array from WPF Brushes?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, foreach, brush

I'd like to make an array of the existing `Brushes` in `WPF` so that I can loop them and show the list inside a combo box. How can I do this?

I have something like this but it won't work because `Brushes` isn't an array.

```
string[] brushes = Brushes;

foreach (string s in brushes)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Reflection. You can use an anonymous type to hold both the name and the brush.

```
var values = typeof (Brushes).GetProperties().
    Select(p => new { Name = p.Name, Brush = p.GetValue(null) as Brush }).
    ToArray();
```

You can access the names only through:

```
var brushNames = values.Select(v => v.Name);
```

Comment: @Mir  Your response helped me a lot. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. This is an `excellent` example of showing how you can even extract an array of multiple values from `typeof(Brushes).GetProperties()`, for example `Name` and `hexadecimal` of a color such as `Yellow , #FFFFFF00`.